# I need to validate filename and extension in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

The filename should have 3 or more characters followed by . and file extension of type : pdf,doc,html. 
This is the regex i am using, but it doesn't work.

```
        /^[A-Za-z]{3}\.?[pdf]|[doc]|[html]$/
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Type what you have into https://regex101.com/ and look at what it means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misused character classes (`[...]` that match 1 symbol) for grouping construct (`(...)` that are used to group alternatives of sequences of symbols). Also, you declare the `.` as optional with `?`, but it should not (acc. to your specifications). Also, 3 or more means you need a `{3,}` limiting quantifier, not a `{3}` (that matches exactly 3 occurrences of the quantified subpattern).

Use

```
/^[A-Za-z]{3,}\.(?:pdf|doc|html)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJ2rX8/2).

Or, to make the whole pattern case insensitive:

```
/^[a-z]{3,}\.(?:pdf|doc|html)$/i
                               ^
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]{3,}` - 3 or more ASCII letters
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `(?:pdf|doc|html)`  - a non-capturing group matching either `pdf`, `doc`, or `html` sequence of characters
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Thanks :) Very helpful